# an example on thread synchronization using semaphore

Tags: semaphore, thread-synchronization

I'm having a hard time working on process synchronization with semaphore. Basically, I failed to see how interruption could disrupt the program, and construct scenarios to issue the problem. Below is a problem I've stuck for a few days. Please help out. Thanks in advance!

Description: The “H2O” problem.

hReady() and oReady() are functions "generating" H and O. Each H thread and O thread executes hReady() and oReady(). Upon ready of TWO H and ONE O, one of the procedure must call makewater(). Solution should avoid starvation and busy-waiting. Also assuming FIFO policy for thread wake-ups.

Approach 1: Any problem in this approach? (Answer is Yes. And I can understand why.)

```
int numHydrogen = 0; 
sema_t pairOfHydrogen = 0; 
sema_t oxygen = 0; 

void hReady() { 
    numHydrogen ++;                // I'm assuming here should have a mutex
    if ((numHydrogen % 2) == 0) { 
    signal(pairOfHydrogen); 
    } 
    wait(oxygen); 
} 

void oReady() { 
    wait(pairOfHydrogen); 
    makeWater(); 
    signal(oxygen); 
    signal(oxygen); 
}
```

Approach 2: Any problem? (Answer is Yes. But I'm not quite sure why. Also how to construct a specific scenario?)

```
sema_t hPresent = 0; 
sema_t waitForWater = 0; 

void hReady() { 
    signal(hPresent); 
    wait(waitForWater); 
} 

void oReady() { 
    wait(hPresent);       // It seems something wrong here. I'm not sure why
    wait(hPresent);       // Also here. Why?
    makeWater(); 
    signal(waitForWater); 
    signal(waitForWater); 
}
```

Approach 3: Assuming LIFO for thread wake-ups in approach 2. Any problem? 
(Also Yes. But why? How wake-up policy comes to part of the play in this question? )

Is there any easy way to sort out similar questions? And how should one think about constructing a scenario? Again, thanks for any help!

Comment: What is your problem? Also, your approach#2 is horrendously wrong. One should never wait twice in a row for a semaphore. That is a lovely bed for deadlocks.

Comment: I failed to construct scenarios to describe the potential problem. Especially in approach 2 and 3, how thread wake up policy could affect ? It seems to me that O thread could always find 2 H to make water.

Comment: Could you please show more of your code? I don't see how you start the thread and where. They are important, I sense deadlocks.

Comment: In approach 2, could consecutive claims on one counting semaphore result in deadlock? Since there may exist many H threads, which could come to rescue...  In that case, I'm assuming I just wasted one pair of O and H.(apologize to ask this kind of question...)

Comment: Ah.. This is not real program. It was assigned as an analysis topic. Here is the original description on "starting processes":  …The trick is to get two H atoms and one O atom all together at the same time. The atoms are threads. Each H atom thread executes a procedure hReady() when it is ready to react; and each O atom 
thread invokes a procedure oReady() when it is ready. …

Comment: Oh I see! Well, is there any comment on what is the limit of the semaphore? I.e. the maximum number of 'open doors'. So from my understanding there are threads that randomly call hReady or oReady depending on their type, right?

Comment: Yes. There's no limit on semaphore count.

Comment: Actually if you are using POSIX, the maximum value of a semaphore is `SEM_VALUE_MAX`

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1**

Scenario: `hReady` is launched before `oReady`.

What happens in `hReady` thread:

1. Construct one H
2. Do we have a pair of H ? -> Nope (don't signal)
3. Wait for O (blocked)

What happens in `oReady` thread:

1. Wait for H2 (don't have -> blocked)

So your 2 actors are blocked, because `hReady` produces only one H instead of 2 and waits for an O that will never come (because he's also waiting).
Also as you noticed, `numHydrogen` might need R/W protection.

**Approach 2**

Pretty much the same case: when you launch `hReady` you are blocked on `waitForWater`.
First wait in `oReady` is unlocked but second will last forever since you don't signal `waitForWater`

I didn't understand approach3 though...

Comment: I may not describe the problem clearly... Originally, there may exist many O and H. Each one of them could launch a thread (oReady() or hReady()), randomly. And there's no limitation on the total number of running/blocked threads. So, it would be possible 2 independent H launched 2 threads, and each is blocked by waiting for O separately....

Comment: Ok I didn't understand it that way sorry.
For me, the main issue in 1st approach is that `numHydrogen` is not protected against competitive access. Therefore 2 H-threads might compute at the same time `numHydrogen % 2 == 0`.
I fail to see what could be wrong in the 2nd if you considering FIFO policy for threads wake-up. In LIFO policy however, the 1st blocked H-thread might never wake-up if the production of H is faster than the production of O.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You are right about 2nd, I made sure about the answer in class earlier. If FIFO is used, the blocked H-O pair in FIFO queue will always get another H at some point, and form water. Yet, LIFO is not the case. As long as the arriving order is not [2*H and 1*O] (could be H-O-H-O... or H-O-O-... or any not 2H1O), no water will be formed. Your post is really inspiring, thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice, then don't hesitate to upvote it if you found it useful ;)